# Creating a named pipe doesn't work from WinUI3 packaged app

Tags: c#, security, package, named-pipes, winui-3

I am creating a named pipe from WinUI3 packaged app. This is a piece of code and it works fine when I launch the application from Visual Studio 2022:

```
 PipeSecurity ps = new PipeSecurity();

 var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null);
 var everyone = sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));

 var sid1 = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null);
 var system = sid1.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));

 ps.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(everyone, PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));            
 ps.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(system, PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));            

 using var server = NamedPipeServerStreamAcl.Create("pipenamehere", PipeDirection.InOut, 2, 
                PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.None, 0, 0, ps);
```

But when I make a sideloaded package, it fails with the following exception:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.
> at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream.Create(String pipeName, PipeDirection direction, Int32 maxNumberOfServerInstances, PipeTransmissionMode transmissionMode, PipeOptions options, Int32 inBufferSize, Int32 outBufferSize, PipeSecurity pipeSecurity, HandleInheritability inheritability, PipeAccessRights additionalAccessRights)

I tried to add various permissions, set full trust and even change the pipe name, this didn't help. What can be the problem of packaged app can't create a named pipe?

Comment: Your app is probably deployed under virtualization. Have you checked your setup accordingly with the official doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes#types-of-desktop-app you need `uap10:RuntimeBehavior="packagedClassicApp"` and especially `uap10:TrustLevel="mediumIL"`.

Comment: According to the Doc:[Pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/communication/interprocess-communication#pipes)  Named pipes in packaged applications must use the syntax `\\.\pipe\LOCAL\` for the pipe name.

Comment: @SimonMourier uap10:TrustLevel="mediumIL" really helps. When I set full trust permissions, it is working. Will you post the answer?

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT Yes, I know this is requirement but it seems it is never checked and doesn't influence the pipe work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packaged apps may run virtualized/isolated in an [AppContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/appcontainer-isolation) or as a full trust app.

From the [Understanding how packaged desktop apps run on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes#types-of-desktop-app) official documentation:

> ... the **uap10:TrustLevel** attribute (of the same Application element)
> determines whether or not your packaged app's process runs inside an
> app container.
>
> 1. A full trust app. Declared with **uap10:TrustLevel="mediumIL"**.
> 2. An appContainer app. Declared with **uap10:TrustLevel="appContainer"**. Runs
>    in a lightweight app container (and is therefore isolated using file
>    system and registry virtualization). For more info, see MSIX
>    appContainer apps.

It looks like you want a packaged + full trust app so you must declare **uap10:TrustLevel="mediumIL"**.